# Erro ao consumir API GitHub V3 utilizando HttpClient ou mesmo HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, api, github

Não estou conseguindo consumir a API GitHub V3 com autenticação básica (sem usar Octokit). Sei que funciona com RestSharp mais quero saber o por quê de não funcionar com `HttpClient` e `HttpWebRequest`.

Sempre obtenho a mesma resposta :

> "Ocorreu um erro de violação de protocolo"

Segue o meu código:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.GetAsync("https://api.github.com/emojis").Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = response.Content; 
        string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar **HttpClient** recomendo utilizar **async e await** para as chamadas, o que torna o código eficiente para chamadas externas, realizei um teste e funcionou, segue o código, lembrando que foi necessário informar um Header.

```
public async Task GetGithub(){
      using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Other");

        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.github.com/emojis");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseContent = response.Content; 
            string responseString = await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado mesmo, eu já uso com async e await mais já estava testando de tudo sem encontrar o problema, que era o Header, só coloquei o header que usou e funcionou